# Проверка посетителя, авторизирован или нет

Tags: php, javascript, opencart

Не пойму как лучше/качественней реализовать.
Логика: Посетитель первый раз на сайте (не авторизирован/не зарегистрирован) выводится попап.  Зарегистриррован - ничего не выводим.
Работаю с Open cart. нашел обрывки информации, что можно 2мя путями - как то проверять через сессии. Как хз..   И второй - по id пользователя. если авторизирован у него она должна быть... где ее "ловить" пока ищу..

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    echo "<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#setCookie").click(function () {
$.cookie("popup", "24house", {expires: 0} );
$("#bg_popup").hide();
});

if ( $.cookie("popup") == null )
{
setTimeout(function(){
$("#bg_popup").show();
}, 4000)
}
else { $("#bg_popup").hide();
}
});
    </script>"
```

Еще нашел аля готовое [решение](http://dimox.name/popup-window-on-first-web-site-visit/) ( не сочтите за рекламу ). НО!  Т.к. будет еще учитыватся, зарегистрирован пользователь (в момент визита) или нет не совсем подходит..

Answer (score 1):

Проверка залогиненного пользователя в **`opencart`**:

```
// в контроллере той страницы(представления), где будете проводить проверку
$data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();

// в файле представления этой страницы:

// для opencart 2.x
<?php if($logged) { ?>
    // action
<?php } ?>

// для opencart 3.x
{{ if logged }}
    // action
{{ endif }}
```